# Как в одну переменную вместить 2 значения от flag.Arg

Tags: golang

Коротко
Входные данные: 1 = one two three
2 = one two

Выход: 1 *one two* three
2 *one* two

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    pulse := flag.Arg(0)+ " " + flag.Arg(1)
    fmt.Printl("*"+pulse+"*", flag.Arg(2))
```

Где ошибка?..

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в написании названия метода:

```
fmt.Printl**n**
```